# Java - Weblogic - JMX : request available free memory on all servers

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx

Once I get a JMX connection to my master weblogic server, how can I retrieve the current available free memory for each of my registered servers ?

I have requested the DomainRuntimeServiceMBean and listed all its attributes and operations, but I can not found anything related to memory.

(I'm using weblogic 9.x)

Answer (score 3):

Weblogic 9 has the JVMRuntimeMBean documented [here](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/wlsmbeanref/core/index.html). You'll need to search for `weblogic.management.runtime.JVMRuntimeMBean`

The listed attributes are

```
•HeapFreeCurrent 
•HeapFreePercent 
•HeapSizeCurrent 
•HeapSizeMax 
•JavaVendor 
•JavaVersion 
•JavaVMVendor 
•Name 
•OSName 
•OSVersion 
•Parent 
•ThreadStackDump 
•Type 
•Uptime
```

Comment: Thanks Josek for this useful link. I still need to figure how weblogic jmx beans are organized. I don't find the structure easy to understand and right now I am not able to request this JVMRuntimeMBean.